# Create JSON from Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, nsdictionary

How can I create a `JSON` object with `NSJSONSerialization` from a Core Data entity and its 1:m children?

When trying to output the fetch request to a `NSDictionary` before converting it to `JSON`, I get a flat `NSDictionary` without any relationships or my app crashes when setting `propertiesToFetch` to a relationship.

This is my code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest 
   fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ContrSector"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"industries"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext 
    executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`propertiesToFetch` expects instances of `NSPropertyDescription`, so try replacing @"industries" with:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSEntityDescription entityForName"@ContrSector" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext] relationshipsByName];
NSAttributeDescription *industriesRelationship = [attributes objectForKey:@"industries"];

request.propertiesToFetch = @[industriesRelationship];
```

edit: I didnt realise this was a to-many relationship, from the docs:

> The property descriptions may represent attributes, to-one
>   relationships, or expressions. The name of an attribute or
>   relationship description must match the name of a description on the
>   fetch request’s entity.

Comment: It crashes with `Invalid to many relationship ((<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x10057ac90>), name industries, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity ContrSector, renamingIdentifier industries...`

Comment: what is the crash when just using "industries"?

Comment: `-[NSSQLToMany foreignEntityKey]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100185460`